# Windows Movie Maker freezes when I touch the timeline?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-movie-maker

When using Windows Movie Maker under Windows XP, if I click on the timeline then WMM freezes and I'm forced to close it.

Everything had been working fine until I added a title to the video. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does adding a title to a new, blank project cause the same issue?  Does it freeze with high CPU usage, or almost none?

Comment: no. I think the problem might be with the video format of the videos i've been working with (MPEG-2) as i had to download a codec to support them (elecard MPEG2 plugin for WMP).  I checked when i clicked to freeze it, and the CPU usage stayed the same (around 55%), but it works fine at high and low usage. The only trigger seems to be with clicking the timeline.

Comment: You have a dual core computer I suppose (two CPU graphs in task manager)?

Comment: yes, i do. the comp is a Dell XPS 410 or something

Comment: So that means that it hangs busily doing something on the CPU (the other option was that it was looking for some file, which would cause a hang with 0% CPU or very close).

Comment: I tried saving what i had of the video, and i received an error that told me that it couldn't find the source files for the clips i used.  i haven't deleted, moved, or changed the folder or files that I imported them from. could this mean something?

Comment: That might be related.  Did any of them come from a USB stick or other removable drive?

Comment: No, i had them emailed to me, .MOV format, saved them to a folder, downloaded a converter, and changed them to MPEG-2, and saved them to a different folder. I imported the MPEG's and i was able to put them all in the timeline, no hassle, and as soon as i added the title, it hung after i clicked the timeline.